# Failing to setup keycloak quarkus version

Tags: keycloak-connect

while doing the setup of keycloak quarkus first we need to run the kc.bat file in windows but while running the bat file in cmd i am getting c:\program is not recognised as internal or external command, Even though i have added the root path in environment variables.But still am getting the same error

Comment: What command do you use to launch kc.bat? Seems like it contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Helo Ashis,
you need to setup system root directory path inside the Environment variable,i hope it will works fine.

Comment: It seems OP wrote that they had already done so.